# Namespace to call the Computers Search Feature?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am in VB.net and wondering if there is a way to call a search from a console application.
For example when the user clicks cancel on the Input Box it brings up the file browser for their computer allowing them to choose a place to save the file.

I am attaching some code just to give hte idea of what I am doing

```
'If User Chooses to Auto Search Then
    If StorName Is "" Then StorName = MsgBox("Please Choose the Location you would Like to Have the Information Written to")
    'Shows msgbox stating to brose for location
    Dim MsgBoxResultStor As Object
    Dim StoragePlace As String
'??which Namespace etc to call??
    MsgBoxResultStor =
    StoragePlace = MsgBoxResultStor
    StoragePlace = InputBox(MessageStor, TitleStor, StoragePlace)
```

FINAL EDIT: Used Save FileDialog instead but same Idea.

```
Dim MyStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim SaveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    Dim msgboxResult As Object
    If StorName Is "" Then StorName = MsgBox("Please Choose the Location you would Like to Have the Information Written to")
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        MyStream = SaveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        If (MyStream IsNot Nothing) Then
            MsgBoxResult = SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`FileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx) class that is part of the [`System.Windows.Forms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Getting an Error saying it Cannot be used as Expression

Comment: @harper89 - You need to new it up as an object. Check the example on the linked `FileDialog` page.

Comment: Now saying Initial Directory Not find. Updated Questions with new code

Comment: Scratch that I have got it. Thanks. Updated Post to reflect my answer.